# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInitialProps')

Tags: next.js, error-handling

I have a next app and want to render custom error pages using `_error.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import CustomError from "../components/Error";
import { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from "next";

interface ErrorProps {
  Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, any>;
  pageProps: any;
  statusCode: number;
  err: boolean;
}

class Error extends React.Component<ErrorProps> {
  static async getInitialProps({
    Component,
    ctx,
  }: {
    Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, any>,
    ctx: NextPageContext,
  }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    const { res, err } = ctx;
    const isErr = err ? true : false;

    return {
      pageProps,
      statusCode: res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404,
      err: isErr,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, statusCode, err } = this.props;

    if (statusCode === 404) {
      return (
        <CustomError
          statusCode={404}
          statusMessage={"Page could not be found"}
        />
      );
    }
    if (statusCode === 500) {
      return (
        <CustomError statusCode={500} statusMessage={"Internal server error"} />
      );
    } else if (err) {
      return (
        <CustomError
          statusCode={statusCode}
          statusMessage={"Something went wrong"}
        />
      );
    }

    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  }
}

export default Error;
```

I know that this error page only works in production env so I have deployed it using vercel here: [link](https://type-io.vercel.app/), I am doing this so that I can apply themes to the error pages as well since it is not possible with statically served error pages

I am getting the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInitialProps')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are checking if the component has `getInitialProps` :

```js
if (Component.getInitialProps)
```

but `Component` can be `undefined` in some cases so you have to handle its existence as well :

```js
if (Component?.getInitialProps)
```